# Properties of functions having the form $g(x,t) = t f(\frac{x}{t})$

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I have been frequently coming across the function $g(x,t) = t f(\frac{x}{t})$ in my course on convex optimization. A friend of mine mentioned that it is the perspective function, but the book on convex optimization by Stephen Boyd gives a different definition of the perspective function.

This function also has the property of being convex in both $x$ and $t$ if $f(x)$ is convex. Does this function have any specific name so that I can look up its properties?

Comment: Can you cite your Stephen Boyd source? My recollection is that this is precisely the definition of perspective he uses, with of course the requirement that $t>0$.

Comment: I am sorry. It was my mistake. I got confused between the perspective function and the perspective 'of' a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a subtle difference in nomenclature. What you've defined is what Boyd and Vandenberghe call the perspective **of** a function (c.f. Section 3.2.6), not the perspective function/mapping (c.f. Section 2.3.3). As they state, the concepts are related:

> Therefore $\text{epi } g$ is the inverse image of $\text{epi } f$ under the perspective mapping that takes $(u, v,w)$ to $(u,w)/v$.

In other words, the epigraph of the perspective of a function is the inverse image of the epigraph of the function under the perspective mapping.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot.